# What were the logistics of "Science Fair: The Series"?

Tags: science-fair-the-series

This weekend I watched National Geographic's show "Science Fair: The Series". This is a documentary mini-series that followed a handful of high school students competing in science fairs, from their local regional and state competitions up to the International Science and Engineering Fair.

In the finale, all the students they showcased were among the top prize winners in their categories, and one was even the "Best in Fair" winner. How did the filmmakers accomplish this? There were thousands of participants from all around the world, they'd have to be extremely lucky to have cameras on so many winners.

Did they have film crews following dozens of students with projects that had a good chance of winning, so they could later edit it down to the stories of winners who also happened to have interesting back stories?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The makers pre-selected kids whose projects and scholastic track records suggested that they would do well, along with those receiving extra support from their (expensive, private) schools. They then salted in other children whose stories they thought that audiences would find inspirational.

> **Costantini:** *That’s a big part of what goes into us choosing different students over other ones. **It’s easy to cast the perennial powerhouses, the people who always win.** But the long shots and underdogs are the harder ones to pick. There are several students in our series where the science fair was their way out.*
>
> *It was the thing that would get them into college or get them money for college. For those kids, the stakes felt high. Most of the other kids will be okay. They’ll go to great schools and go on to great things whether or not they win this science fair. I think you get so invested in the students that a science fair win will be the difference between them getting a scholarship and then going to a great program where they’ll be able to continue their interests. As a filmmaker, you try not to get too invested in any of the stories, but it’s impossible because you’ve been following them for so long.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Exclusive Interview with Directors of National Geographic’s Science Fair: The Series](https://innotechtoday.com/exclusive-interview-with-directors-of-national-geographics-science-fair-the-series/)</sup></sub>

Using pre-existing ISEF records they were able to identify schools with a strong track-record of creating previous International Science and Engineering Fair winners. They then filmed a selection of kids from those schools that the teachers suggested were likely to enter and do well. Chloe Hindes, for example, was one of *twelve* children filmed at Monte Vista High School.

> Adams told Harvey, they were looking at doing a six-part series
> instead of a movie and were considering Monte Vista because of its
> “track record” with ISEF. “I'm like wow that's incredible,” Harvey
> said. Adams said they can see the ISEF records, and kids from Monta
> Vista come up quite a bit. [...] Twelve students — Urianna Acosta,  Marissa Martinez, Maria Sears,
> Angelina Vargas, Carlos Ochoa, Gus Miller, Jack Noonan, Grace
> Goodland, Claire Seger, Joseph Benavides, and Chloe Hindes — were part
> of the filming process for the series along with Harvey.
>
> <sub><sup>[MVHS students featured in Nat Geo ‘Science Fair: The Series’](https://alamosanews.com/article/mvhs-students-featured-in-nat-geo-science-fair-the-series)</sup></sub>

Similarly, several of the featured students come from Jericho High School, NY, where an especially inspirational science teacher (the same teacher featured in the TV series' forerunner, the 2018 documentary [*Science Fair*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7153434/), was able to pre-select students that she thought would do well.

> Legendary from the Science Fair film is Dr. Serena McCalla and her
> students from Jericho High School in Jericho, NY. The series chooses
> to continue following her drive to push students to be the best they
> can be. Anyone who knows anything about the desire to get to ISEF
> quakes in their boots thinking about the kids from Jericho.
>
> <sub><sup>[Media Mindfulness Blog - Science Fair: The Series](https://media.pauline.org/Resources/Blog/ArticleID/1901/Science-Fair-The-Series)</sup></sub>

Their '*long shots and underdogs*' include students like Memory Bvungo, Endrick Garcia-Torres and Savdiel Santana who had entered and won other science competition prizes (including from [the ISEF itself](https://abstracts.societyforscience.org/Home/GetSearchResultsFromRequest?ISEFYears=0%2C&Category=Any%20Category&AllAbstracts=True&FairCountry=Any%20Country&FairState=Any%20State)) in previous years.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: @Barmar - I've found a bit more about the selection process.

Comment: Jericho also had a similarly strong track record, and their teacher probably identified the likely winners.

Comment: The real miracle seemed to be Memory from Zimbabwe.

Comment: @Barmar - Interestingly she was an ISEF finalist in 2018, 2020 and 2023 for various projects, starting at the age of 14. I'm assuming it wasn't much of a leap that she'd get a prize; https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LRWR.png

Comment: @Barmar - The teacher at Jericho seems to be a science whizz and is very involved in promoting the ISEF to her students.

Comment: Yes, she was quite impressive (as were all the featured students, of course).

Comment: I went to an upscale public Long Island HS in the 70's (not too far from Jericho), there was nothing like that going on. But we did hear impressive things about Bronx Science and Stuyvesant (I was a Mathlete, they were the strongest competition).